# Adding height for menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a menu that have the height of the displayed area, the images below is to understand better.

Image 1:

[image: No need for scroll]

If there’s no enough content to scrollbar to appear, the menu should have the height between the header and footer.

Notes:

1: The menu and header is fixed.

2: The menu have scroll: auto, so if there’s no space for the sub-menus to display will create a scrollbar.

Image 2:

[image: More text]

If there’s enough content to scrollbar to appear, the footer will be at the bottom, the menu should have the height of the window – header. menu = window-header.

Image 3:

[image: Footer almost appearing]

When scrolling down a piece of the footer will appear, the menu should have the height between the height and the piece of footer.

I made a code with javascript that accomplish what I desire, but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this code without controlling the scroll, load and posterior resize for calculating the height of the menu. Because If I add a breadcrumb or something it’ll need more calculations.

To add content to see what I desire just press the button and when scrolling down you’ll see the menu adjusting its height. To open the menu just click the button at the header.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/gk5fL1nr/4/`
```

Limitations:

Need compatibility with IE8+.

Notes:

I doesn’t want equals height because I can’t know the height of the content so it could be bigger than the expected.

I doesn’t want to fix the height of the menu, because the sub-menus is different for every user (some have more privileges than another’s).

Someone knows why there’s a bug when adding some context (not so much) and scrolling down It’ll comes back at the top(because of the fixed option),generating a infinite loop?.

Sorry if someone doesn’t understand my question, because English is not my primary language.

TL;DR – I just need the same resource that’s is in the link with css.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uvsvbqds/1)**

html

```
<header>this header is fixed</header>
<section>
    <div class="left">menu</div>
    <div class="right">scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>scrollable
        <br/>
    </div>
</section>
<footer>this is fixed footer</footer>
```

css

```
header, footer {
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    height: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
header {
    top:0;
}
footer {
    bottom:0;
}
section {
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #666;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
body, html {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.left, .right {
    position:absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}
.right {
    background: #aaa;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left:100px;
    overflow:auto;
}
.left {
    width: 100px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, if there's more sub-menus in the menu it will display over the footer.

Comment: No, it will not.. try it.